# PowerShell Batch ConvertImage

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell function that will convert jpg to png. I got that to work. I cannot figure out how to get it to delete the original jpg file after finishing. I have attempted to use the del and remove command but cannot delete the original file because it is still being used in the process. I have also tried to end the process but it ended the whole process when I put it within the foreach loop. Is there a way to get it to end the process so the file can be deleted and then continue through the rest of the images? Below is the code that converts but does not delete. If there is a better way to do this I would like to know were I can improve. Thank you !

```
    function ConvertImage{
        param ([string]$path)
            $path=Convert-Path . #path to files
        if (Test-Path $path)
     {
    #Load required assemblies and get object reference
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
        foreach($file in (ls "$path\*.jpg")){
            $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
            $newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace '([^.]).jpg','$1') + ".png"
            $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "png")
            $file.Fullname
        }  
     }
        else
     {
        Write-Host "Path not found."
     }

    };ConvertImage -path $args[0]
```

How Do I use an integer with leading zeroes for the code below:

```
function ConvertImage{

param ([string]$path)

    $Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input new name'
    $Start = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input start number'
    $Ext1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Initial Extension'
    $Ext2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Ending Extension'
    Write-Host "You input '$Name' and '$Start'"
    Write-Host "You input '$Ext1' and '$Ext2'"

$i = "{0:D2}" -f [int]$Start

Get-ChildItem ("*.$Ext1") | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("$Name"+"_"+"$i.$Ext1" -f $i++)}
Get-ChildItem ("*.$Ext2") | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("$Name"+"_"+"$i.$Ext2" -f $i++)}


$path=Convert-Path . #path to files
    if (Test-Path $path)
 {
#Load required assemblies and get object reference
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    foreach($file in (ls "$path\*.$Ext1")){
        $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
        $newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace "([^.]).$Ext1",'$1') + (".$Ext2")
        $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "$Ext2")
        $file.Fullname
        # Dispose file to stop using it
        $convertfile.dispose()
        # In brackets in the event that the filepath has a space
        Remove-Item "$($file.Fullname)"
    }  
 }
    else
 {
    Write-Host "Path not found."
 }

};ConvertImage -path $args[0]
```

Comment: Add a call to [`Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Dispose) to release the resource.

Comment: @vonPryz I am probably making a mistake when using it because I cannot seem to get it to work it says it doesn't recognize the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a `Remove-Item` at the end of your `foreach`.

```
function ConvertImage{
    param ([string]$path)
        $path=Convert-Path . #path to files
    if (Test-Path $path)
 {
#Load required assemblies and get object reference
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    foreach($file in (ls "$path\*.jpg")){
        $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
        $newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace '([^.]).jpg','$1') + ".png"
        $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "png")
        $file.Fullname
        # Dispose file to stop using it
        $convertfile.dispose()
        # In brackets in the event that the filepath has a space
        Remove-Item "$($file.Fullname)"
    }  
 }
    else
 {
    Write-Host "Path not found."
 }

};ConvertImage -path $args[0]
```

Comment: For a second I thought it would work. I tried something similar previously. The issue still remains. I cannot remove the Item. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Throwing in a `.Dispose()` should close the file so you can delete it. Unless it does not have the method available to it. You may need to do a `$convertfile.dispose()`

Comment: Thank you vonPryz and Drew everything works now there are no errors. I wish I knew about Dispose before hand.

Comment: @Daniel It's a common pitfall, as most of the stuff in Powershell just works out of the box. As a rule of thumb, if one is dealing with .Net classes instead of native Powershell cmdlets, one should check MSDN in case of caveats.

Comment: Do you guys mind helping me a little more? I have more I am trying to do with this and getting stuck.

Comment: Edit the question and we will try.

Comment: @DrewLean Updated.